# Stop to execute delegated functions in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I do have a problem to stop executing functions, I'll try to explain what I want to do and how I'm trying to do it.

For example, I bind some event on element `a or button` and I'd like to user will not click it again, I mean they can click it, but all actions will not be called for some time (say a second).

So, here is some examples:

In html

```
1st example 
<ul>
   <li><a href="some url" class='button'>Click me</a></li>
   <li><a href="some url" class='button'>Click me</a></li>
   <li><a href="some url" class='button'>Click me</a></li>
</ul>

2nd example somewhere else:
<section id='someid'>
   some info
   some articles - doesn't matter
   <button class='button iLoadComments'>Load more comments</button>
</section>
```

In JavaScript:

```
$("ul").on("click","a.button",function(){
   ... here some code or ajax request, whatever
   return false;
});
$("section").on("click","iLoadComments",function(){
   ... some ajax request
   return false;
})
```

and I'd like to not allow to execute it,
and I want to cover ALL code by one function.

So, what I did: globally I defined a new event listener and add attribute `disabled` to that element

```
$("body").on("mousedown", ".button", function(e){
    var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.attr("disabled")) {
        var event = e || window.event;
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () {
           $this.removeAttr("disabled");
        }, 1000); 
        return false;
    }else{
       $this.attr("disabled", true);
       
    }
});
```

but the problem is delegated function will execute anyway!

Could somebody help please, is there better practise, or way to correct that way?

Comment: `a` elements don't have a `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var click_enabled  = true;
$("body").on("click",".button",function(){
   if (click_enabled) {
        click_enabled = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
            click_enabled =  true;
        }, 1000);
   } 
   return false;
});

$("ul").on("click","a.button",function(){
    if (!click_enabled)
        return false;
   //... here some code or ajax request, whatever
});
$("section").on("click",".iLoadComments",function(){
    if (!click_enabled)
        return false;
   //... some ajax request
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAhK4/

Comment: `flag` isn't a very descriptive variable name. It's a flag indicating what? I think `enabled` would be more appropriate.

Comment: actually, it's not really smart way.. i'd like to do it globally, i mean a lot other elements and functions... and cover it just in one place

Comment: $('body').on('click','a.button, a.button1, a.button2',function(){ ... } instead of $('ul').on(...

Comment: @salexch, i edited question, i hope i was able to explain correctly

Comment: yes.. I added a comment just before your edit.. check it if it suits you

Comment: @salexch, is it some way to not add a flag `click_enabled` inside each function ? because i want to do it in existing project and it's not fun to add any flag in every function..

Comment: @salexch - this is one of the solutions, thank you for patience ))) it looks good )), but is it not any way to do it as i wanted and gave example ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.on`. With that, your handler will run only once:

```
$("ul").one("click","a.button",function(){
   //... here some code or ajax request, whatever
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will enable the link again.

Comment: yes, it's not a solution, because i'd like to stop it just for second and reenable again

Comment: Hm, you could use `setTimeout` to bind with `.one` again after a second. Not sure how efficient that would be, though. Maybe selexch's answer is the way to go.